# Highcharts - Cross browser charts have different Y axis ranges, how can I ensure consistency?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to graph data on our site. Unfortunately we have to support internet explorer, and naturally, highcharts renders differently in IE than in Chrome.

The problem I'm having is that the charts have different Y ranges in chrome than in internet explorer. Is there a config setting I can use to make the ranges consistent? Here are screenshots of what I'm talking about:

**IE** (Desired Result)

[image: Chart in IE]

**Chrome** (Incorrect)

[image: Chart in Chrome]

I'm looking for a config option for the tick intervals. Notice in IE the Y axis on the left is in multiples of 250, whereas chrome is in multiples of 200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your code this is only a guess since you may have already done this. Try using the yAxis property [`max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max). This will let you set the maximum range for the yAxis. Same can be done for the [`min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min).

Finally, use [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) to set the range between steps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was aware of min/max, I'm looking for a config option for the tick intervals. Notice in IE the Y axis on the left is in multiples of 250, whereas chrome is in multiples of 200.

Comment: I answered my own question here haha, the property is called tickInterval, when used alongside min to ensure they start at the same point I get the result I needed - thanks!